# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre las palabras "deberes" y "tarea"?

Tags: traducción, diferencias-regionales

Estoy completando la primera semana de mi segundo año de español en mi escuela. Tengo una maestra nueva y ella es de España (es su primer año en los Estados Unidos).

En mi primer año de español mi maestra nos enseñó que la palabra "homework" en español es "tarea," pero mi maestra actual enseña que la palabra "homework" en español es "deberes" no "tarea" y "tarea" en inglés es "sheet".

Sin embargo, para el traductor de Google "tarea" y "deberes" son sinónimos y en inglés es "homework", por lo que estoy muy confundido.

¿Cuál es la diferencia entre las palabras "deberes" y "tarea"? ¿Tiene razón mi maestra actual, o es el traductor Google o qué?

**Nota: Prefiero un repuesta en inglés porque solamente he estudiado español durante un año.**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the Real Academia Española (**[RAE](http://www.rae.es)**) [Royal Spanish Academy]:

> [**tarea**](http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/srv/search?id=XN3ZjqlbEDXX2tXTXf1C).
>
> (Del ár. ṭaríḥa, y este de la raíz del ár. clás. {ṭrḥ}, echar).
>
> 1. f. Obra o trabajo.
> 2. f. Trabajo que debe hacerse en tiempo limitado.
>
> [**deber**](http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/srv/search?id=iYwm4d4aXDXX2oyE3aFP%7CcMpuUTV5XDXX2IGHD4Lj).
>
> 3. m. Ejercicio que, como complemento de lo aprendido en clase, se encarga, para hacerlo fuera de ella, al alumno de los primeros grados
>      de enseñanza. U. m. en pl.

---

I would tell you that in Latin America, **"homework"** is **"tarea"**. Everything that is assigned by a teacher in the school or institution. I travelled for many countries in Latin America and everyone does the same translation.

---

**"Deber"** is equals to "duty" or "must". It's an obligation.

---

**"Chore"** is equals to "tarea del hogar"

---

**"Task"** is also "tarea" but it's more like an activity. Something that it's need to be done in order to fulfill a work. Imagine a process of credit card delivery.

You need to follow these steps:

1. You do a submission for a credit card in a financial institution
2. Then the submission will be evaluated by someone else
3. Then the submission will be approved by another person
4. Once approved, they will give you credit card

The process of credit card delivery is composed by 4 steps or tasks. These steps must be done in a period of time and assigned to someone. If one of these steps are not done, the process will fail.

It's probably that in Spain they use "deber" as a homework. But in Latin America is "tarea" for sure.

Some countries like Cuba (Caribe) they tend to say also "deber".

**PS:** Look something interesting on the RAE definition. **Deber** comes from Latin "debere", but **tarea** comes from the Arabic word **taríha**. Remember, in the past (711 AD) Arabs warriors invaded Spain for many years and they influenced the Spanish language.

---

**EDIT**

As many others have said, it's true when you try to use **deber** as a meaning for "homework", some people use **deberes** (in plural). However, this implies that you have many things to do. And in singular it would sound a little weird "Tengo un deber que hacer", in that case could be translated like "I have a duty". If you analyse both terms carefully by their definition according to the RAE, they are synonyms. Furthermore, I remark that in Latin America is very common the use of **tarea**. And as others have already confirmed, in Spain they use **deberes** (And according to Gorpik in some regions of Spain, they use also tarea). When I wrote this answer for your question, I didn't mention that the use of one or another is incorrect. Let me clarify that both are valid. There's no wrong answer, but I tried to give you the real definition according to the RAE, which is very important to us no matter where you are from. If you live in America, you should know now what translation fit well to you.

Comment: +1 Gracias. Porque yo solamente completo un año de español el texto es poco difícil, pero yo comprendo más de texto.

Comment: @Cicero, What about now. I'm glad that you are interested on Spanish. Good luck.

Comment: I don't think it is necessary to translate RAE. To me, Royal Spanish Academy sounds weird : )

Comment: @MaximusDecimus Es mejor.

Comment: Be aware of that *U. m. en pl.* (*Usado más en plural*) in the definition of *deber*. In Spain, the most usual word is *deberes*; the singular (*deber*) would sound outfashioned, though in other countries it might be usual nowadays. I certainly remember my grandma asking me about *el deber* when I was in school, a long time ago.

Answer (score 5):

In Spain they use `los deberes` instead of `tarea` and that explains why your current teacher told you so. Both terms are correct and they are synonyms as google prompted you, however, I would say that `tarea` is more widely accepted and understood(at least in Latin América) while `deberes` is only used in Spain.

Comment: Some parts of Spain also use *tarea* and, in my experience, this word is widely understood in all the country, though it is true that *deberes* is more usual in most parts of Spain.

Answer (score 2):

As Maximus Decimus says, **`tarea`** and **`deberes`** mean ***`homework`*** depending on the region where you are.

### According to the REAL ACADEMIA ESPAÑOLA (RAE):

> ### [tarea](http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/srv/search?id=XN3ZjqlbEDXX2tXTXf1C). *(Del ár. ṭaríḥa, y este de la raíz del ár. clás. {ṭrḥ}, echar).*
>
> 1. f. Obra o trabajo.
> 2. f. Trabajo que debe hacerse en tiempo limitado.
> 3. f. Afán, penalidad o cuidado causado por un trabajo continuo.
> 4. f. Cuba y Ven. deber (‖ ejercicio que se encarga al alumno).

---

> ### [deber](http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/srv/search?id=cMpuUTV5XDXX2IGHD4Lj).
>
> 1. m. Aquello a que está obligado el hombre por los preceptos religiosos o por las leyes naturales o positivas. El deber del cristiano, del hombre, del ciudadano.
> 2. m. deuda (‖ obligación de pagar).
> 3. m. Ejercicio que, como complemento de lo aprendido en clase, se encarga, para hacerlo fuera de ella, al alumno de los primeros grados de enseñanza. U. m. en pl.

### And according to the ACADEMIA MEXICANA DE LA LENGUA (AML):

> ### tarea
>
> s.f.
>
> 1. Actividad, trabajo: A Guillermo le gusta hacer sus tareas lo antes posible.
> 2. Trabajo escolar: Juan puede salir a jugar cuando termina su tarea.

---

> ### deber.
>
> v.tr.
>
> 1. Tener la obligación de hacer algo: Debes hacer la tarea.
> 2. Tener una deuda: Pedro me debe mucho dinero. || s.m.
> 3. Aquello que se está obligado a hacer: El deber de los padres es cuidar a sus hijos. □ Cuando es verbo se conjuga como tejer.

You can see that the RAE definition says that in Cuba and in Venezuela it is used **`tarea`** for ***`homework`***, it is the same for Mexico and I would say that many other countries from Latin America.

**Conclusion**

Both words are correct and you should use them both depending on where you are in order to the people can understand what you say. **`Tarea`** in Cuba, Mexico or Venezuela (for sure) and **`deberes`** (more common in plural) in Spain. This is similar for British or American English for instance. Also, Google is right too but it fails in saying where (which location) is the translated word used.

Answer (score 1):

En mi país,  Venezuela, le decimos tarea al "homework". En otros países, le dicen deberes. En general las palabras son sinónimos de homework.

> Trabajo escolar (denominado, según el país o las circunstancias, como tarea o deberes) es el trabajo que se asigna a los estudiantes por sus profesores, y que se indica que debe completarse, en su caso, fuera del aula y de la jornada escolar, en el entorno doméstico, con o sin ayuda de la familia.

Comment: Disagree, in México we use tarea as well.

Comment: Bueno en realidad lo digo por novelas y películas mexicana. Gracias por la corrección.

Comment: Even in movies and soap operas the term ¨deberes¨ is never used for ¨homework¨. The verb ¨deber¨ is used, indeed, but not as replacement for homework and maybe that´s why your confusion. I´m just saying it to clarify ;)

Comment: En un colegio mexicano: http://blog.colegiowilliams.edu.mx/ideas-para-hacer-deberes-escolares-en-casa, solo por eso lo decía. Tampoco es que soy un experto en la cultura mexicana, y por me parece muy acertada tu opinión! Muchas gracias.

Comment: Por cierto, es mejor opinar en inglés? Estoy usando esta aplicación desde ayer, y no conozco todas las normas.

Comment: Debe tratarse de un colegio internacional y por lo tanto utilizan ¨deberes¨ por la influencia Española, creo. Por otro lado, me parece que es mejor opinar en Inglés ya que no todos los usuarios dominan Español y de esa forma éstos últimos quedan excluidos de poder entender dichas respuestas o comentarios. De hecho en la pregunta original, el autor especifica que prefiere una respuesta en Inglés debido a que no domina muy bien el Español. Bienvenido al sitio!

Answer (score 0):

In Colombia **deberes** means your obligations within a wide scope, starting from your obligations as a citizen,  and then it drills down to your legal obligations in a contractual relationship.  In english the eaxct t word that defines **deberes** is **duties**.  **Tareas** means exactly tasks,  things to do.

Answer (score 0):

La palabra "tarea" además de la escuela, puede usarse en más ámbitos. Por ejemplo las tareas del hogar con las que suelen referirse a las que hacen las amas de casa... o las tareas de bricolaje.

"Deberes" puede emplearse para recalcar que es algo que debe hacerse... pero normalmente se usa en el ambito escolar.

No me expreso muy bien en ingles, lo siento... podría contestar en inglés pero me quedaría con la duda de si me he expresado correctamente... o no he hecho otra cosa aparte de confundirte.

Si alguien domina el inglés y me entiende... agradeceria que dejase un subcomentario a mi comentario en el cual traduce mi mensaje.